# Adding Kali repositories has changed the output of lsb_release on Debian host

Tags: debian, package-management, kali-linux

I installed Kali in virtualbox with Debian as my host. I've done it several times. But, when I reboot my host I noticed Debian is missing from the list of OS'es in the GRUB menu. It's showing Kali. The only OS on this machine is Debain.

When I click it, it boots Debian. It's odd because I have never installed Kali on my main drive, only in Virtualbox.

I checked the GRUB config file, and I noticed this:

```
lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
```

When I run that on Debian the output is

```
root@Sophie:/home/sophie# lsb_release -i -s
Kali
```

How and why did virtualbox do this and how do I fix it?

**cat /etc/os-release**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0 (moto)"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="1.1.0 (moto)"
VERSION_ID="1.1.0"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kali.org/"
```

Edit:

Some day sago I did add the Kali repositories to install something, then I removed it. Could that have done it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `cat /etc/os-release` on the host. Could you have edited that file by mistake? I don't see how the guest OS could have affected the host in any way.

Comment: I will post output now. I haven't touched anything apart from installing Kali in virtualbox.

Comment: Oh wait, I did add the Kali repos. Could that have done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the Kali repositories would indeed change the `/etc/os-release` file. The version in Kali's repos is probably newer than the one in Debian's so `apt` downloaded it and replaced the one on your system. If you're very, very lucky, that's all that broke.

Do not, I repeat *not*, ever mix repositories from different Linux distributions.

Comment: Oh dear, another reinstall :( Lesson learnt.

Comment: @BandAid15 you might not need a reinstall. If that's all that broke, you can just edit the file manually and change it back. In any case, if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Is there any way to check what has last been updated and from which repo it updated from?

Comment: a reinstall mean the opportunity for more practice ... just make sure your data is backed up properly

Comment: @BandAid15 not sure, you should have a look at `/var/log/apt/hostory.log` but that won't show the source repo. That's probably worth asking a separate question.