# Can I use the kali linux repositories from a debian installation?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, repository

I'd like to install some of the applications in the Kali distro on my Debian installation.

- Is it possible?
- Would you recommend to add the Kali repositories and just install them?
- Would that cause any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, please refer to http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/10/30/add-official-kali-linux-repositories/

I added kali linux repositories in my ubuntu 14.04, and successfully installed kali tools like sqlmap, join-the-ripple.

The problem after adding kali linux repositories i found is lsb_release changed from ubuntu to kali. This is annoying, because the release info is frequently used in scripts.

See also: [Adding Kali repositories has changed the output of lsb_release on Debian host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192872/adding-kali-repositories-has-changed-the-output-of-lsb-release-on-debian-host) .

Answer (score 0):

To avoid some problems of mixing repositories, you can edit the [APT preferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences)  as pointed in this blog http://blog.romaingre.net/2014/05/add-kali-repository-on-debian/